# How do I set up React-spring in codepen?

Tags: reactjs, codepen, react-spring

I tried to create a basic setup to start practicing react-spring in CodePen, but it shows an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I don't know why this happens and how to fix it.

This is the code of my app so far (as you can seee, it's super short):

https://codepen.io/Nerdifico/pen/oNxXNPv?editors=0010

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codesandbox maybe an easier option.
Here is an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jn3z28ry33

Comment: Have you ever tried to do it with code pen? If it worked, how?